# How do I enable the dynamic crosshair via the console?

Tags: counter-strike

In counter strike 1.6, the crosshair should be decreased when you duck.
But in my version it doesn't.  Is there any console commands for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the console in the game and type

```
cl_dynamiccrosshair 1
```

That should do the trick.

Alternativly, you can add it to your autoexec.cfg.

More about crosshairs in 1.6 can be found here:

http://www.nextlevelgamer.com/counter-strike/counter-strike-crosshair-setup